# PHP rewrite links using .htaccess file

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there any nice function for PHP to use Apache's mod_rewrite to rewrite URLs?

```
$url="semantic/path/to/page";
$url=mod_rewrite_url($url,"path/to/.htaccess");

//$url is index.php?page_id=45
```

I had the idea of simply parsing .htaccess file and comparing it to the string with url, but I'm more interested in some built-in function, which I doubt that exists though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PHP framework that incorporates URL rewriting (or "routes" as they call it). Some of these frameworks (and links to their routing mechanisms) include:

- [CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html)
- [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html)
- [Symphony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html)
- [CodeIngniter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: I'm trying to avoid any frameworks - I just don't like them. Thanks for answer though.

Comment: Having made a framework myself (in use in my own sites) I would recommend at least examining the methods that Cake and CodeIgniter employ. I found it tricky to manage nice mvc style urls, but those frameworks at least helped me understand how they achieved it for my comparison.

Comment: I'm thinking of redirecting all URLs to index file, and then let it decide using previous request URL.